# My function not show result, how return my function?

Tags: php

Hello i have problem with my function, how i will return my if lines?
Here is my function codes...

```
function hastalik($val1, $val2) {
$dizi2 = implode(",", $val2);
$sonuc= explode(",", $dizi2);
echo "Have you ever had?<br>";
foreach ($val1 as $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $sonuc)){
        echo "$value : YES<br>";
    }else{
        echo "$value : NO<br>";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your function *echos the output*, it doesn't *`return`* it to the caller, so there's nothing to assign to `$hastalikSONUC`. You need to concatenate a string and `return` it instead of just `echo`ing it.

Comment: Can you show in example like my function please?

Comment: `$str = 'Have ...'; $str .= "YES"; ... return $str`

Comment: i did but not working now all return empty

Comment: Update your question to show your attempt.

Comment: i did but still closed :(

Comment: Where are you concatenating and `return`ing a string here?!

Comment: in function if and else lines like " $str = $value." : YES<br>";   return $str; } else { $str = $value." : NO<br>";  return $str; ........ Like this but return one result not loop...

Comment: `$str = 'Have ...'; foreach (...) { $str .= "..."; } return $str;` — *Concatenate* inside the loop, *`return`* after the loop.